# In iOS apps, is Bundle Id or SKU visible to customers

Tags: ios, bundle

When creating a new app, I had to choose a Bundle Id and SKU in iTunes Connect.
Are those in any way visible to the end user?
I am pretty sure that they are not visible in the "normal" scenarios (e.g. AppStore, installed apps, etc.), but what about when you make a backup of the apps on your computer or some other advanced scenario?

Answer (score 3):

Bundle ID can be found with dev tools or something like iExplorer. SKU is not visible anywhere.

Comment: Bundle ID can also be found by viewing the package contents of an app (downloaded to a mac) and viewing the Info.plist